# Объяснение правописания слова "выспятся"

Tags: орфография

В ЕГЭ по русскому языку в слове "высп*тся" (они) надо вставить букву. Понятно, что это буква "Я", но почему? Образовано от глагола 1 спряжения — выспаться, значит, в личном окончании пишем "Ю"?! Что это?

Answer (score 4):

Если личные окончания глагола **ударные,** то спряжение определяется **по окончаниям;** при этом не имеет значения, какой гласный в инфинитиве. Поэтому глагол *спать* II спряжения: *сп**и**м, сп**и**шь, сп**и**те, сп**и**т, сп**я**т.* К тому же спряжению относятся и все производные от *спать* приставочные глаголы с безударными окончаниями, такие как *выспаться.* Поэтому *высп**я**тся.* Сюда же относится, к примеру, глагол *гореть:* он имеет ударные личные окончания II спряжения, поэтому на инфинитив мы внимания не обращаем.

В школе вторую часть правила (о том, что у глаголов с ударными личными окончаниями тип спряжения определяется по окончаниям) нередко опускают, т. к. определять тип спряжения надо для того, чтобы правильно писать безударные личные окончания. Если же личные окончания ударные, то никаких трудностей в написании они не вызывают, а следовательно, не надо думать о том, к какому типу спряжения относится глагол.

Comment: Замечательное подробное и правильное объяснение.